# Path definition in makefile

Tags: path, compiler-errors, makefile

I have a doubt about indicating a path in makefile and I'd like to have a clarification.

Suppose my structure is made this way:

```
/home/machinename/softwarefolder/mainfolder
--------------------------------------------> /subfolder1
--------------------------------------------> /subfolder2
```

This means that both subfolder1 and subfolder2 are at the same nesting level in /mainfolder.

Now I'm compiling something inside subfolder 2 (this means that I cd to that folder) that uses a configure file with a macro pointing to a path that, in my case, it's in subfolder1.

This configure file used by the program in subfolder2 to compile is generated automatically by the program itself after running ./configure

The automatically generated configure file has the macro defined this way

```
MACRO    =  ../subfolder1
```

Do the two dots (..) indicate, as in the cd command, "go back one step" (and, therefor, the configure file is pointing to the right folder)?

If the answer to the first question is "no", then why substituting the aforementioned macro with

```
MACRO    =  /home/machinename/softwarefolder/mainfolder/subfolder1
```

generates a "missing separator" error in compile-time?

Sorry for the probably trivial question and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make doesn't interpret the content of variables in any way, for the most part.  The question of how the `..` will be interpreted depends entirely on where the variable is used.  If it's used in a place where a path like `../subfolder1` makes sense, then that's how it will be interpreted.  If not, not.

Since you don't show how `$(MACRO)` is used, we can't help.  But in general the answer to your question is "yes, it means go up to the parent directory".

As for your second question, there is no way I can envision that changing just that one line will result in a "missing separator" error.  Maybe your editor "helpfully" made other changes to the file such as removing TABs and substituting spaces, or adding TABs?  TAB characters are special in makefiles.

If you want help with the second question you must provide (a) the exact error you received (cut and paste is best), and (b) the exact text of the rule in the makefile at the line number specified in the error message.

Comment: the macro is referred in the following way:
first in another macro`MACRO2 = -I$(MACRO1)/otherdirs/otherdirs`, and then in compilation rules for suffixes like `.F.o: $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS)  $(MACRO2) $<>$*.f90`. 
As soon as you suggested the TAB I think I understood the problem: I opened the configuration file with OpenOffice (Ubuntu did it automatically) and it probably substituted "hard tabs" with "soft tabs" (i.e.: spaces). Thanks for the help!